# How to save both matching and non-matching from grep

Tags: unix, grep, pattern-matching, matching

I use grep very often and am familiar with it's ability to return matching lines (by default) and non-matching lines (using the -v parameter). However, I want to be able to grep a file once to separate matching and non-matching lines.

If this is not possible, please let me know. I realize I could do this easily in perl or awk, but am curious if it is possible with grep.

Thanks!

Comment: better go with perl, awk doesn't support perl regex, but grep does...

Comment: Good to know... also, how does the speed of pattern matching compare between a perl script and grep? I use these commands on 100G files with billions of lines.

Comment: and what do you mean "grep a file once"? can one use tmp file ? :D  you want to have two output files? one with match one with unmatch?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify... I want to run the grep command a single time on one file and produce two output files, one matching, and one non-matching.

Comment: Perhaps this is impossible??

Comment: You said "run grep cmd **a single time** "... you mean by using those options... I don't think it is possible...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it does NOT have to be grep  - this is a single pass split based on a pattern  -- pattern found > file1  pattern not found > file2

```
awk '/pattern/ {print $0 > "file1"; next}{print $0 > "file2"}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Does awk support full regex (perl style regex)? The previous post suggestion avoiding awk because of regex limitations.

Comment: You decide what you need - you said 'unix' which may or may not exclude GNU awk - http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html.  On solaris,  nawk has decent regex features.

Comment: `awk '{print > (/pattern/ ? "file1" : "file2"}' inputfile`

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and I wrote a small Perl script for that [1]. It only accepts one argument: the `regex` to *grep* input on.

> [1] https://gist.github.com/tonejito/c9c0bffd75d8c81483f9107c609439e1

It reads **STDIN** by line and checks against the given `regex`, matched lines go to **STDOUT** and not matched go to **STDERR**.

I made it this way because this tool sits in the middle of a pipeline and I use shell redirection to save the files on their final location.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Read the file

Step 2 : Replace spaces with a new line and save the result in a temporary file

Step 3 : Get only lines contains '_' from the temporary file and save it into multiwords.txt

Step 4 : Exclude the lines that contains '-' from the temporary file then save the result into singlewords.txt

Step 5 : Delete the temporary file

```
  cat file | tr ' ' '\n' > tmp.txt | grep '_' tmp.txt > multiwords.txt | grep -v '_' tmp.txt > singlewords.txt | find . -type f -name 'tmp.txt' -delete
```

Comment: Seems like, it takes much time to complete the execution. Let's assume there are 1 million lines.