# Split file contents to different files

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a sample file like this.

```
this is a sample_file for testing single_words and
multiple_words from
file
```

I want single words and words containing _ in different files.

singlewords.txt

```
this
is
a
for
testing
and
from
file
```

multiwords.txt

```
sample_file
single_words
multiple_words
```

The input text file is around 30gb. What is the best way of doing this operation?

Added from comment:

tried `egrep -o '\b(\w*_\w+)\b' words.txt > multiwords.txt`. but not sure how to write remianing words to next file

Comment: dirty but it should work: `sed -e "s/ /\n/g" your_file | grep -v "_" > singlewords.txt` and `sed -e "s/ /\n/g" your_file | grep "_" > multiwords.txt`

if your file is too big you can previously split in several chunks with the `split` command

Comment: @oguzismail tried egrep -o '\b(\w*_\w+)\b' words.txt > multiwords.txt. but not sure how to write remianing words to next file

Comment: grep has -v flag, given that it'll output only non-matching lines

Comment: @Jotne let's not start an edit war

Comment: Also there is this dupe [How to save both matching and non-matching from grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789228/how-to-save-both-matching-and-non-matching-from-grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > ($i~/_/?"multiwords.txt":"singlewords.txt")}' file
```

Result

```
cat multiwords.txt
sample_file
single_words
multiple_words
cat singlewords.txt
this
is
a
for
testing
and
from
file
```

Not sure how well it handles 30GB file, but can test it out.

Comment: @oguzismail This I do understand, but no need to remove what he tested from the comment that i have added to the post for other to find.